# no such column in sqlite android java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i try to retrieve data from sqlite with this code:

```
String sql = "select * from "+Table +" where "+C_LoginName+"=" +user; 
Log.d("CREATE DATABASE", "SQL: " + sql);   
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);  
c.moveToFirst();  
Log.d("Password is", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(C_Password)));
```

but this error shown to me ("no such column....")
i even use single quot(') side every string but not different.but when i use select * from table the loginName is there.
how can solve that?
tnx

Comment: More than likely `C_LoginName` does not match the actual name of the column

Comment: Please provide C_LoginName :) and be sure C_LoginName is actually in your database columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes missing around `user`. Also, make sure `C_LoginName` contains a valid column name.

```
String sql = "select * from "+Table +" where "+C_LoginName+"='" +user + "'";
```

Comment: i add quot but not different

Comment: @user2580975 Please, post what's logged as sql.

Comment: just put single quot around user, i put to any string that used,tnx

Answer (score 0):

> no such column in sqlite android java

This kind of error is usually thrown:

- When you forgot to wrap column's value into single quotes (if you are
  not using parametrized statements)
- You specified icorrect column name(check your database schema)

**Recommendation:**

I don't like your approach. It's dirty, not very human-readable and very unsafe. I suggest you to use parametrized statements with placeholders where each placeholder will be replacted with value from specified array.

Example:

```
String query = "select * from tablename where name = ?";
db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {name}); // ? will be replaced with name value
```

**Note:**

Usually if you are dealing with database it's very good and handy practise to create some class for example called Const that will hold your column names as final static variables.

This provides more efficient and cleaner dealing with database and you'll avoid typo problems (which are too hard to find out).